# How to hook into the quick edit action?

Tags: functions, hooks, actions, quick-edit

I found this solution to [automatically assign parent terms when a child term is selected](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100707/automatically-assign-parent-terms-when-a-child-term-is-selected), which is working fine for the **save_post** hook:

```
add_action('save_post', 'assign_parent_terms');

function assign_parent_terms($post_id){
global $post;

if($post->post_type != 'product')
    return $post_id;

// get all assigned terms   
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'product_cat' );
foreach($terms as $term){
    while($term->parent != 0 && !has_term( $term->parent, 'product_cat', $post )){
        // move upward until we get to 0 level terms
        wp_set_post_terms($post_id, array($term->parent), 'product_cat', true);
        $term = get_term($term->parent, 'product_cat');
    }
  }
}
```

As I have a large number of posts, I need to hook into the **quick edit action**, not just into the save-post action.

Anybody has a solution of this hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two flaws in the code that I can see. The first one is a bug in this code

```
if($post->post_type != 'product')
```

If no post exists, you get the following error

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object...

This can be fixed by first checking if a post `isset`

```
if(isset($post) && $post->post_type != 'product')
```

Secondly, [`wp_set_post_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms) should not be used for custom taxonomies on custom post types, the correct function should be [`wp_set_object_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms). From the codex page

> This function will only work on the native post type. For a taxonomy on a custom post type use `wp_set_object_terms()`

So, your code should look something like this

```
add_action('save_post', 'assign_parent_terms');

function assign_parent_terms($post_id){
global $post;


if(isset($post) && $post->post_type != 'product')
    return $post_id;

// get all assigned terms   
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'product_cat' );
foreach($terms as $term){
    while($term->parent != 0 && !has_term( $term->parent, 'product_cat', $post )){
        // move upward until we get to 0 level terms
        wp_set_object_terms($post_id, array($term->parent), 'product_cat', true);
        $term = get_term($term->parent, 'product_cat');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This absolutely fixed my problem!!! Many thanks Pieter!

Comment: My pleasure. Glad I could help

Comment: @PieterGoosen: lets just use the second argument for the hook which is the `$post` object and remove the global. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`save_post` is actually called on saving a post through the Quick Edit feature as well. As we find from the source code, the `save_post` action is called from two functions: `wp_publish_post` and `wp_insert_post`, the latter being called both when saving a post through the normal process and when saving a post through the quick edit process!

So, the code as you currently have it should work for Quick Edit as well!

Comment: Its not working for me, when I use the quick edit with the code above, the parent term is not added automatically when the sub term is selected.