# Category control subcategories

Tags: categories, wp-admin

After hours of googling and no result I am turing to you.

I have a Wordpress site where me and my colleagues publish information to the rest of the company. There are several screens put up on different locations (even different cities). Each city have their own category and each category have subcategories which tells us where in that city the screen is. For example I have three screens in one city called *"City"*. Each screen has its own subcategory as follows:
*"Location 1"*
*"Location 2"*
*"Location 3"*

What I want is when you create a new post and choose category, all subcategories under *"City"* get checked so that I don't have to check all of them one by one to publish on all.

The easiest way would be if there already was a plugin for wordpress, but if there aren't I could give it a shot of making my own plugin, or simply change the code. One reason I am using Wordpress though is that I am not very good at programming websites with database and all the rest that Wordpress has. Is there anyone that have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: what you are looking is here, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100708/63430